# Lumen 5.2 authentication through jwt

Tags: php, jwt, lumen-5.2

I am newbie to `Lumen`, i tried to authenticate my users through an access token, i followed all steps in the following blog [JWT with Lumen](https://laravelista.com/json-web-token-authentication-for-lumen/)

in getting the token (login) step i always get the following error:

> BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 839:
>
> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $app ]]
>   in class Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager

i am using `lumen 5.2` with `php 5.5.12`

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you look in your composer.json file you'll see that Lumen requires a minimum PHP version of 5.5.9, but your problem is not from that.
You need to register the Cache Service provider. 
I found a quick hack to it posted on a forum somewhere else by adding this code to bootstrap/app.php file.

```
$app->alias('cache', 'Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager');
$app->alias('auth', 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not Worked in 5.2 getting error>>>>>>>>>>>>>Cannot declare class Auth, because the name is already in use